# Asus n53sv (preinstalled Windows + recovery partition) - HDD broken, how to get Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

My HDD broken in Asus n53sv, I bought new one. I dont have Win7 installation DVD I only have product key on back side of my Asus. I could download Win7 iso installation DVD, install it and provide this key, would it work?

If yes - I dont have DVD room, but I have USB case for SATA drives. Could I install it to USB using WinToUSB and after installing iso to this USB could I connect the drive to SATA slot? Would it boot ?

Comment: Why my quesion is -1 to rating? I am struggling with restoring my Win7 for 2 days and can't find any solution even in this forum..

Answer (score 3):

Enter your product key here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7.

You will get download links for your version of Windows 7. They expire after 24 hours. Download the appropriate ISO(32 or 64 bit).

To make a bootable USB use this program:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool.

Insert your new HDD and plug in the USB flash drive.

Check your boot priority settings in BIOS and set your USB as the first device. Save the settings and reboot.

If everything is right, you should see Windows 7 installation starting. Your product key should work.

Comment: Ok so I am trying to download it from here: microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 and i put product key there and it says Error: The product key you entered appears to be for software pre-installed by the device manufacturer. Please contact the device manufacturer for software recovery options.

Comment: You must call Asus then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rufus (https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to burn Windows 7 Installer (download from Microsoft with your product key) to a USB pen drive (or to a primary partition on your new HDD) which you can boot from and install Windows 7 to your new HDD (without using a USB case if you use a pen drive). Personally I dislike WinToUSB because it makes some modifications to system folders. It's probably nothing harmful but still better safe than sorry.

Comment: Ok but what with my Win7 key, can I use this on the back side of my laptop? I quite strange as theoretically I could to it on other machines too... How it works - would WIndows be activated and genuine?

Comment: you should install whatever windows version your laptop came pre-installed with. for example if it was windows 7 home premium before the accident then you should install windows 7 home premium on new hdd too. it'll activate smoothly if you do so.

Comment: Ok so I am trying to download it from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7 
and i put product key there and it says Error: The product key you entered appears to be for software pre-installed by the device manufacturer. Please contact the device manufacturer for software recovery options.

Comment: You can use other ways to grab an installation media (contacting your laptop manufacturer or downloading untouched iso images from trusted sources)  and there shouldn't be any problem as long as you use your own key to activate it.

Comment: Ok I have iso but how to check it it is untauched? Some checksum? Where are original checksums? How to check my iso checksum?

Comment: I've downloaded Win7 ISO not from MS pages, I check its genuity and I have doubts:
The Win7ISOVerifier says that: The specified ISO file is not recognized Windows 7 image. I installed it on USB HDD and it boots OK but before using it I must check its genuity.


    MD5: C30DDF270DA6E5D00A03AF794C27298A
    SHA1: 1700A1C8BA8EE07F21609C8DBD7A4CDF4CCC257F
    SHA256: 9C9470837778ECC436E04D075539AA8F9E65D269804C3B5F85401160A6A9B9FE
    SHA512: 21B088358FEFD40A68948C7B460CAC5B504E550263FE5900FDBE1E5AA69F82D125AEAF29955C9C7AE22E8623272136130FB4559B60C9AE705BF5BC9613E52F82

So it is genuine or not?